# iterating over files in folder using os python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, operating-system, directory

**Ultimate Goal:** Iterate over many files in a folder to perform a specific set of tasks.

**Immediate Goal:** Load next file (`file2`) to perform tasks

**Background:** I am using the following code

```
import os

folder = '/Users/eer/Desktop/myfolder/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if not item.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, item)): #gets rid of .DS_store file
            print(item)
```

**Output:** `print(item)`

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
(etc...)
```

I am using the following code to open the first `file`:

```
data_path = folder + item
file = open(data_path, "r")

#perform a set of tasks for this file
```

This works well for opening the first file, `file1.txt` and performing a set of tasks.

However, I am not sure how to load `file2.txt` (and eventually `file3.txt` and `etc...`)so I can continue the task performance

**Questions:**

1) How do I put this code in a `for` loop? (so I can load, and perform tasks on all the files)?

Comment: Put the processing in the `for` loop? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I just updated my question...but yes, a for loop, if that would solve the problem

Comment: You have the `for` loop already, it's where your `print` statement is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the file operations in the same loop like:

```
import os

folder = '/Users/eer/Desktop/myfolder/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if not item.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, item)):
            data_path = folder + item
            with open(data_path, "r") as file:
                ... use file here ...
```